# What was Hermione Granger's boggart form?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

[Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger) says: "*Boggart: Failure*".

What was the specific form that the boggart took for Hermione?

Ron would like to know too:

> He seems like a very good teacher", said Hermione approvingly. "But I wish I could have a turn with the boggart --"
>   **"What would it have been for you?" said Ron, sniggering. "A piece of homework that only got nine out of ten?"**
>   -- <sub>"Prisoner of Azkaban", Ch 7.</sub>

Comment: General reference? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermione_Granger#Personality

Comment: [Unfulfilled potential](https://youtu.be/QCOXARv6J9k?t=20s)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Specifically, it was Professor McGonagall informing Hermione that she had failed all her exams.

> Hermione did everything perfectly until she reached the trunk with the Boggart in it. After about a minute inside it, she burst out again, screaming.
>   ‘Hermione!’ said Lupin, startled. ‘What’s the matter?’
>   ‘P-P-Professor McGonagall!’ Hermione gasped, pointing into the trunk. ‘Sh-she said I’d failed everything!’
>   It took a little while to calm Hermione down.
>   *Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 234 - Bloomsbury - chapter 16, *Professor Trelawney's Prediction*

I should say that this occurred during final exams in year three and that it could technically be referring to just those exams or all her classes overall. Due to the context, that they were in the middle of exams, I tend to err on the side of Hermione failing just her exams. It *could* be construed otherwise, though, so that possibility remains open.

Comment: This is nicely in line with what Hermione says about the love potion in GF.

Comment: Hermione's biggest fear is Professor McGonagall, Neville's biggest fear is Professor Snape, and they say Lord Voldemort's only fear is Professor Dumbledore (though it's actually not his boggart form).  Hogwarts professors are  scary.

Comment: @b_jonas We don’t know for sure—Dumbledore might be Voldemort’s boggart form! (Though I guess it’s more likely to be Death itself or something like that. Or perhaps love.)

Comment: @JanusBa: we do know, there's a relevant JKR interview about the Dark Lord and boggarts: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12570/4918

Comment: @b_jonas Ah, never saw that before!

Comment: That's kind of weird. So Boggarts can turn into specific situations, rather just shapeshift into things?

Comment: I identify with Hermione so much.