# What is Dumbledore's Boggart?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

<sup>[Continuing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167218/what-is-voldemorts-boggart) the Boggart series of Questions</sup>

## What would Dumbledore see for a Boggart?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## His sister Ariana dead

Source: [J.K. Rowling's web chat transcript as of 30/07/2007](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript/)

> Lucy: What is dumbledores boggart?
>
> J.K. Rowling: The corpse of his sister

Comment: That's just wrong, Jo.

Comment: So many corpses...I feel like people who fear death (or the death of a loved one) shouldn't see the corpse itself, they should see the means of bringing it about (whatever that is to them).  Dumbly can't possibly fear the death of his dead sister...can he? *Good answer, though...straight from JKR*

Comment: That's a surprise. I would have guessed either Grindelwald or Voldemort standing triumphant over the wizarding world.

Comment: Doesn't surprise me at all. I would have guessed this myself if JKR hadn't already made it canon.

Comment: It devastated him and is the cause of many of his decisions, particularly bad ones like putting on the Resurrection Stone ring. It happened decades before this and still ultimately led to his death. It had power over him. Also, I think it's a fear of facing up to it, not just a fear of its existence.