# Why did Voldemort not seek out multiple means of preventing death during his first reign?

Tags: harry-potter

In The <strike>Sorcerers</strike> Philosophers Stone, we learn about the stone and Nicholas Flamel who has lived for nigh on 600 years. Surely Voldemort would have heard of him as famous of an Alchemist as he was as well as this, Flamel had ties to Dumbledore making it even more likely that Voldemort would know of him.

Presumably, based on the stories of terror from his first reign he held more power back then. I'm unsure if Dumbledore was keeping the stone way back then (possible avenue to look into) but I would presume that if he weren't then Voldemort could have easily taken it from Nicholas.

**What would stop a man so devoted to avoiding death to not seek one of most famous delayers of death?**

Comment: Possible dupe? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/77393/3567

Comment: The key here is Voldemort's arrogance. His crowning achievement are the seven Horcruxes - to seek the philosopher's stone is to admit that his achievement is flawed.

Comment: So, what, one form of _immortality_ isn't enough for you?  Geez, you're never satisfied, _Voldemort's Dad!_

Comment: @Voldemort but isnt the simple fact of creating multiple horcruxes and hiding them all at different locations admitting that just 1 is not safe enough?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Dumbledore Says in HBP

> While the Elixir of Life does indeed extend life, it must be drunk regularly, for all eternity, if the drinker is to maintain his immortality. Therefore, Voldemort would be entirely dependent on the Elixir, and if it ran out, or was contaminated, or if the Stone was stolen, he would die just like any other man. Voldemort likes to operate alone, remember. I believe that he would have found the thought of being dependent, even on the Elixir, intolerable. Of course he was prepared to drink it if it would take him out of the horrible part-life to which he was condemned after attacking you, but only to regain a body. Thereafter, I am convinced, he intended to continue to rely on his Horcruxes: he would need nothing more, if only he could regain a human form. He was already immortal, you see ... or as close to immortal as any man can be.' (Albus Dumbledore)

Comment: Seconding this, I think this quote can be considered the canon answer. 
I'd also like to add that if I'm not mistaken, the elixir of life doesn't make one invincible, it only delays natural death. If that is true, the elixir of life would only have solved part of the problem.

Comment: Perfect :) congrats.

Answer (score 6):

1. He was still busy with other things.

   - First wizarding war (he died smack in the middle of trying to win it)
   - Getting his 7 Horcruxes completed
2. Obtaining Sorcerer's Stone from Nicholas Flamel wouldn't be an easy task.

   Voldemort clearly doesn't relish the idea of risking his life by facing a likely more powereful - and immortal - opponent (and 600 year old wizard is not likely to be a pushover). He refused to meet Dumbledore in open battle (the only time he did, was by accident and he ran off the moment Dumbledore was kicking his behind).
3. He's a megalomaniac narcissist with likely OCD. He came up with the 7-Horcrux idea, and pursuing other avenues implies that his brilliant super-idea is fallible. As we see from his conversations with Harry Potter during the final duel, admitting his fallibility isn't very much in his nature.

Answer (score 1):

Also adding to sherin_ 's answer, He wanted to be immortal as a Dark Lord, not as a simple immortal being. He wanted to unite Dark Magic with his immortality, he wanted to dive deep in Darkest secrets.